# how to fix this? the "Scan Screen"

Tags: flutter, image-processing, mobile, camera, scanning

I'm trying to make a mobile app where the "Scan" button is pressed. it will have a camera access and I have another file for the scan screen. I keep getting this error. this is the only error I have. I can't run my code
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have a required parameter there  the `CameraDescription` .

Comment: Please [edit] your post to copy-paste the code and error messages into it as text. See here for why we ask this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>ScanScreen(camera:'CameraDescription')))` would fix it.
ScanScreen widget is asking for required 'camera' parameter which you are currently not providing.